# c++ multimap insert more than two values

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I have found that it's possible to declare such std::multimap:

```
multimap < u_int32_t, u_int32_t,string> lines;
```

If it's possible to declare it then it should be possible to insert too

But I wonder how?

I have tried `std::pair`, but it seems  I need something like `std::triple`.

I know it's possible to decrale some struct and hold into that struct a few values. But I would rather prefer to do it directly. Moreover because it's possible to declare it.

**EDIT** 
I did serious mistake and  it turned out I really understood multimap wrong. 
Screams of people here and downvotes made me to reread documentation.
Now I use it so:

```
struct container {
u_int32_t  size_in_blocks;
string name_of_file;
};
            //size_of_file
multimap <  u_int32_t, container> lines;
       // first value is used as a key for sorting
       // second value is just a storage

container d;// initialization
lines.insert ( std::pair<u_int32_t,container>( total_size_bytes, d) );
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What is your intention? Why do you think you need a `multimap`?

Comment: ok, I need multimap but not map, because  a few files can have the same size, so for avoiding collisions I use multimap.

Comment: OK, that's a valid usecase for multimap. Now, just use it as a normal map. Why do you pass it three template arguments?

Comment: I don't pass now three arguments.  I DID pass, because I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
multimap < u_int32_t, u_int32_t,string> lines;
```

The template parameters for `multimap` are listed at [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap):

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class multimap;
```

The first template parameter is the key,
the second is the type stored,
and the third is the comparator.

You have specified `std::string` as the comparator.  Clearly this won't do what you want, and I'm somewhat suprised this even compiles.  `basic_string` does have an `operator<` -- that must be why it compiles.

I think you are confused as to what `multimap` really is.  `multimap` is not something that can be used to map between a key and one of mopre different kinds of values.  `multimap` is the same as `map` in that it maps between a single key and a value, except the difference is that with `multimap` you can have more than just one value mapped to a single key.

Comment: *"basic_string does have an operator< -- that must be why it compiles."* - This won't make it work either, since the comparator is invoked with the function call operator `operator()` and not `operator<`. Otherwise correct answer, of course.

Answer (score 5):

```
template < class Key,                                     // multimap::key_type
           class T,                                       // multimap::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // multimap::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // multimap::allocator_type
           > class multimap;
```

The third template argument is for comparator. Your code doesn't make any sense. Having a multimap with three types doesn't make any sense either. It maps from keys to values, what the third type is supposed to mean?